# How can I read two variables from a txt file that are on the same line? in python

Tags: python, file, var, readline, separator

lets say you have a basic txt file with:

```
USERNAME(var1):PASSWORD(var2):VAR3
USERNAME(var1):PASSWORD(var2):VAR3
... etc...
```

And I want to be able to read that in my script/code as:

```
Username = var1
Password = var2
something = var3
```

And implement that like:

```
username = var1
password = var2
s.login(var1, var2)

file = open(var3, 'r')
```

I have been spitting through a lot of code, trying to reverse engineer some things, but it's not quite working out.
If someone could shed some light that'd be great.

I need to make these lists myself, so I can use any separator I want (`,`, `;`, `:` etc).

Comment: Have you tried searching? These aren't exactly your problem, but they're probably good starting points to see what kinds of operations you should consider:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936967/text-file-parsing-with-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105456/parsing-data-from-text-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array

Comment: according to my last few sentences in the post: "I have been spitting through a lot of code, trying to reverse engineer some things, but it's not quite working out. If someone could shed some light that'd be great." I've definitely searched for info and starting points, but failed to create something working. I'll add what I've tried so far.

Comment: Thank you for adding that information to your question; it's important.  I did read your last few sentences, but without knowing _what_ you've been looking at or _what_ your best attempt looks like, there's nothing on which to "shed some light".  For example, there's no other way I could know you were getting an `IndentationError`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will be more in detail in my next questions and make sure to add what I've already tried and/or looked at.

Comment: I rolled back this question to remove the "tag" question about an `IndentationError`, which was completely unrelated. This should never have been allowed to stand, certainly not for over 9 years. Questions on Stack Overflow - indeed, everywhere on Stack Exchange - are about a question that is being asked, [not about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/) a task that the OP is trying to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('basic.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        username, password, filename = line.split(':')
        print(username, password, filename)
```

Comment: This looks really neat, and works for one line, but as I commented above:
I've tried this but it's not acting how I want.
I have multiple lines. Each line has different info needed.
for example: each line has a username and password, I want to be able to login on each account for each line in the file.

Comment: If you try it out, you can see that it will print for each line. So you just need to do your login stuff in the loop to make it work for every login combination in your file.

Comment: correct, I made a spelling mistake. It prints it as the following:
('usn2', 'pass2', 'List2.txt\n')
the \n and '', symbols will cause problems in logging in, or won't they?

Comment: @Snowlav You can use `filename.strip()` to remove leading and trailing whitespace (the `\n`). The quotes are not part of the variable’s values but are caused from the `print` statement, so don’t worry about those.

Answer (score 0):

If all lines have the same format, you can split a line in that file into your variables as follows:

```
a_line = "USERNAME(var1):PASSWORD(var2):VAR3"
Username,Password,something = a_line.split(':')

print(Username,Password,something)
```

The result is:

```
USERNAME(var1) PASSWORD(var2) VAR3
```

Or in more general way:

```
all_lines = []

with open('infile.txt','r') as fin:
    all_lines = fin.readlines()


for a_line in all_lines:
    Username,Password,something = a_line.split(':')
    print(Username,Password,something)
```

Comment: I've tried this but it's not acting how I want.
I have multiple lines. Each line has different info needed.
for example: each line has a username and password, I want to be able to login on each account for each line in the file.