# How can I upload the following file into Python to get a specific structure from a file? follow the body to see an example

Tags: python

File:

```
 0 3 3.0277

 0 14 4.8251

 1 6 2.8984

 2 3 4.5238

 2 12 1.9643

3 2 4.5238
```

I need to upload into Python and get in the following form:

```
graph_latency = {'0':{'3':3.0277,'14':4.8251}

,'1':{'6':2.8984}

,'2':{'3':4.5238,'12':1.9362037455854288}

,'3':{'0':4.5238,'2':4.5238}}
```

I'll Appreciate it a lot, Thanks

Comment: What is the "next extructure"? What have you tried so far? What error / output did you get? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text File Parsing with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936967/text-file-parsing-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` for parsing the text:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

data_from_file = """
 0 3 3.0277

 0 14 4.8251

 1 6 2.8984

 2 3 4.5238

 2 12 1.9643

3 2 4.5238"""

def transform_to_my_format(data):
    d = defaultdict(dict)
    for (i1, i2, i3) in re.findall(r'([\d\.]+)\s+([\d\.]+)\s+([\d\.]+)', data):
        d[i1].update({i2: float(i3)})
    return d

pprint(transform_to_my_format(data_from_file))
```

Outputs:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {'0': {'14': 4.8251, '3': 3.0277},
             '1': {'6': 2.8984},
             '2': {'12': 1.9643, '3': 4.5238},
             '3': {'2': 4.5238}})
```

Comment: Thanks Adrej, It is a new language for me and it works great, How can get it from a File? because a file will be an entry for my a code in python. Thanks again

Comment: @Richard You can try `data_from_file=open('path/to/my/file.txt', 'r').read()`

Comment: Hey @Andrej, I need to get the decimal numbers like a number not, string, I mean without ''. not like this '4.8251' -- in this way 4.8251. Due to I need to do some operation...

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I put int(), according to your answer I noticed it's float.

Comment: Can I get you email? I got stuck with a Code and I need a hand. Thanks

Comment: @Richard If you have question, post it here, on Stack Overflow. Surely many eyes will see the error faster.